# Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto. Asp.net MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, poo

[image: cambiando .First() a .FirstOrDefault()]Agregue dos campos más a la clase beneficiario e hice las migraciones ahora me esta mostrando este error.

```css
//Model 
[Table("Beneficiarios")]
    public class Beneficiario
    {
        [Key]
        public  int beneficiarioId { get; set; }
        public string nombreBeneficiario { get; set; }
        public string apellidoBeneficiario { get; set; }
        public string cedula { get; set; }
        public string resolucion { get; set; }
        public string nombreBeneficio { get; set; }
        public string siglas { get; set; }
        public string tipoBeca { get; set; }
        public string estado { get; set; }
        public int mesInicio { get; set; }
        public int anoInicio { get; set; }
        public int mesVence { get; set; }
        public int anoVence { get; set; }
        public int montoTotal { get; set; }
        public decimal montoOtorgado { get; set; }
        public decimal montoPendiente { get; set; }
        public string fuente { get; set; }
        public string codigoPlastico { get; set; }
        public string fotoUrl { get; set; }
        public string firmaUrl { get; set; }
        public bool impreso { get; set; }
        public string carnetFechaImpreso { get; set; }
        public string carnetUsuarioImpreso { get; set; }
```

```html
//Controller
 //
        // POST: FotoCarnet/GuardarFoto
        [HttpPost]
        public RedirectToRouteResult GuardarFoto(FormCollection form)
        {
            string cedula = form["cedula"];
            string imagenBase64 = form["image"];
            string imageSource;
            Image imagen;
            Beneficiario beneficiario = new Beneficiario();
            string[] partesCedula = cedula.Split('-');
            string nombreFoto = partesCedula[0] + "/" + partesCedula[1] + "/" + cedula + ".jpg";
            string folderRaiz = Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/" + partesCedula[0]);
            string subFolder = Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/" + partesCedula[0] + "/" + partesCedula[1]);
            string rutaFoto = Server.MapPath("~/Fotos/" + nombreFoto);

            if (imagenBase64 != null)
            {
                imageSource = String.Format("data:image/jpg;base64,{0}", imagenBase64);
                imagen = Base64ToImage(imagenBase64);

                if (!Directory.Exists(folderRaiz))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(folderRaiz);
                }
                if (!Directory.Exists(subFolder))
                {
                    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(subFolder);
                }
                imagen.Save(rutaFoto, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                var queryBeneficiario = from b in _dbContext.Beneficiarios
                                        where b.cedula == cedula
                                        select b;

                beneficiario = queryBeneficiario.First[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]();
                beneficiario.fotoUrl = nombreFoto;
                _dbContext.SaveChanges();

                RevertirValidarImpresion(cedula);
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Resultados", "FotoCarnet", new { cedula = cedula });
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy lo que me trae el query, pero igual me pide instanciar

Comment: recuerda que FirstOrDefault() devolvera null si en la lista no hay ningun cocincidencia, es pore so que deberias validar que la cedula que asignas en el where exista en la tabla

Comment: Fijate como declarastes en el model las dos variables nuevas si son no null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El valor que intentas obtener para `beneficiario` es nulo, tienes que revisar porque se esta obteniendo un valor nulo de `queryBeneficiario.FirstOrDefault()` :

```
 beneficiario = queryBeneficiario.FirstOrDefault();
```

Al tener un valor nulo, no puedes acceder a la propiedad `fotoUrl` ya que la instancia de `beneficiario` tiene un valor nulo:

```
  beneficiario.fotoUrl = nombreFoto;
```

por esta razón obtienes el mensaje de error:

> Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto

Comment: igual coloque beneficiario = queryBeneficiario.FirstOrDefault(); pero me sale el mismo errore de Referencia a objeto no establecida como instancia de un objeto agradeceria tu orientacion

Comment: revisa el método FirstOrDefault() del query,

Comment: listo lo corregi, entra al beneficiario pero igual me trae null

Comment: beneficiario.fotoUrl = nombreFoto; ahora me marca en rojo aqui

Answer (score 1):

Esto sucede porque al realizar el linq este no retorna ninguna entidad, quiere decir que no hay ninguna entidad con el cedula que defines en el filtro

```
var beneficiario = (from b in _dbContext.Beneficiarios
                            where b.cedula == cedula
                            select b).FirstOrDefault();

if(beneficiario != null)
{
    beneficiario.fotoUrl = nombreFoto;
    _dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

deberías validar si no se encuentra ningún beneficiario con la cedula que aplicas en el "Where"

Answer (score 0):

Valida si el objeto es diferente de null antes de comenzar a usarlo después de cada consulta. Los controles nunca están demás y no cargan tu código.

```
if(objeto!=null)
    //Código si el objeto está correcto.
else
    //Código si el objeto es null. Puedes lanzar una exception!
```

Así también como indican los demas, válida si hay alguien con esa identificación -Los Controles de Condición otra vez- pero nunca usas un objeto que sea llenado por un usuario sin antes confirmar si tiene la información presumiblemente correcta. Siempre confirmar.

Saludos